# How to operate on all of a word without its surrounding space?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor-motions, whitespace

In vim you can do `daw` to delete the entire word, but it also removes the space after the word, (`caw` too).

Is there a way to operate on the entire word without effecting the space around it?

For example

```
a d c
  ^
```

Performing `caw` -> `b`

Gives us:

```
a bc
```

Is there a way spaces can be treated as other delimiters, brackets for eg, which would give us:
 `a b c` ?

---

While this isn't what you would do as a user, it makes writing macros more difficult, since surrounding delimiters aren't as predictable.

Note, this is quite similar to this question, but not identical since the word may be surrounded by tabs or other delimiters.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607904/vim-deleting-from-current-position-until-a-space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `iw` object. For example, `diw` or `ciw` etc. You can read more about the various text objects available to you [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select).

In this particular case, rather than `ciw`, you could just use `cw`, since it happens to be equivalent to `ce`. This is a special case, since for example `dw` *would* delete the extra space. You can read more about this behavior [here in the documentation](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#WORD).

Comment: `cw` doesn't operate on the whole word. `ciw` is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @ideasman42 Yes it does. Unless you are not at the start of the word.

Comment: ... which happens more often? :)